# Lowercase URLs without affecting parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm currently using ASP.NET MVC 4 Routing with the `LowercaseUrls` option set to `true` and it's working great. I'm using this configuration:

```
        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {
                controller = "Inicio",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            });
```

But in a particular set of actions, I have a string `id` parameter that is encrypted and case-sensitive.

Then, when I try to generate an action link like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("My Text", "Action", "Controller", new { id = encryptedString })
```

The `id` parameter in the URL gets converted to lowercase resulting in an error while trying to decrypt the string.

Is it possible to configure routing to lower-case URLs ignoring URL parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure but if you use a query string instead of a route parameter, it should leave it alone?

Comment: It does, but I would really prefer it wasn't a query string value.

Comment: you may can build your own route with a IgnoreRoute disclaimer I have no idea if this can work was just a thought

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've run into this before. What I ended up doing was getting [AttributeRouting](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/wiki/Generating-Lowercase-Outbound-URLs).

They have a sweet feature (linked above) to *PreserveCaseForUrlParameters*.

The other option is to use [LowercaseRoutesMVC](http://lowercaseroutesmvc.codeplex.com/). In this scenario you would make certain routes lowercase and the ones you want to leave alone you can just use `routes.MapRoute` beforehand. However, this can get messy since the specially configured ones will be lowercase where the entire route of the default ones wouldn't be.

Hope this helps!

Comment: AttributeRouting is on the MVC roadmap http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Roadmap

Comment: `AttributeRouting` link is dead.

Comment: @Dementic hey I just fixed the URL for `AttributeRouting`. Thanks for the heads up!