# Make URLs lowercase, but keep route's {id} parameter variable case

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In MVC5 there is an option to make all URLS lowercase by setting `routes.LowercaseUrls = true` in the RouteCollection.  This as expected changes all characters to lowercase, including the `{id}` parameter.

```
routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Is there a way to set all URLS to lowercase, but allow the ID parameter to be variant case? In my system the ID is encrypted, therefore contains both upper and lower case characters.  When returning a lowercase ID I get the error `Padding is invalid and cannot be removed` due to the encrption value being different.

***Edit***

I've since found [Lowercase URLs without affecting parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243847/lowercase-urls-without-affecting-parameters) on StackOverflow which suggests a third-party library [Attribute Routing](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/wiki/Generating-Lowercase-Outbound-URLs) (now deprecated) to be installed.  A solution without installing addiitonal packages would be better for us.

Comment: Out of curiosity - why lowercase all urls?

Comment: It looks like you don't want lowercase URLs so much as case-insensitive URL parts.

Comment: Mainly for standaisation @Evk.  This way all URLs are referenced the same in the the system and its documentation.  It also seems much tidier and removes any user confussion over whether they need to use upper or lowercase characters.  There are a number of articles online arguing for lowercase-only urls, which I've read too.

Comment: I'd then better be more careful with what you lowercase. For example linux file names are case sensetive so if you lowercase file name in url - it might fail with 404 or point to completely different file. Well on the other hand you already see problems with this approach yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you can create IRouteConstraint and do some regex
[Creating a Custom Route Constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs)